# I can not parse xml from URL on objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I am a beginner in objective C , I want to parse a XML file from URL , I found some sample code about NSXMLPARSER and I write this code but it do not work.

please help me.

my xml file is :

```
<list>
<first>apple</first>
</list>
```

... My ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>  {

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextField;

@end
```

...My ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController @synthesize myTextField;
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL { 
    NSURL * xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    NSXMLParser * rssparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [rssparser setDelegate:self];
    [rssparser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict {           

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"list"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        myTextField.text = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"first"];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString * path = @"http://example.com";
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    [super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setMyTextField:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view. 
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown); 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare this is ViewController - is a very bad design. Create a new class (ex XMLParser: `@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>`)
Now call in the initializer method parse. Below sample code:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"guidef" ofType:@"xml"]]];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    return self;
}
```

Now you can declare your methods.

Comment: I didn't understand - how do I call it from my UiViewController if I need to parse and return a new string?

Answer (score 0):

attributeDict holds only attribute values ...

```
<first name="something" last="something" > <sec>some</sec></first>
```

so when you get elementName as **first** attributeDict will have *'name'* and *'last'* and other attributes 
not the child element **sec**